# Apply background color to the container having background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building this page using bootstrap4 framework, and I want to add blue color on the background's to the div carrying "globe-img" class. I tried by wrapping the content in an inner div(an overlay) but that again breaks the grid layout entirely. Is there any possibility to apply the background-color with out adding additional markup.

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.globe-img {
  background: url('http://binarytheme.com/BTlivedemos/2014/10/20/blue-landing/assets/img/earth.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.smicon {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid globe-img">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h1 class="text-center text-white text-uppercase pt-5 pb-4">Design my way</h1>
            <p class="text-white">Nunc at viverra risus. In euismod quam ac dictum varius. Nunc at viverra risus. In euismod quam ac dictum varius. Nunc at viverra risus. In euismod quam ac dictum varius. Nunc at viverra risus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <i class="fa fa-android fa-3x text-white smicon rounded-circle d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center my-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p class="text-white">Android</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="http://binarytheme.com/BTlivedemos/2014/10/20/blue-landing/assets/img/new-i.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
            <i class="fa fa-apple fa-3x text-white smicon rounded-circle d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center my-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p class="text-white">Iphone</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider declaring `background-image` property for your background image, and `background-color` property for your background colour, using the shorthand `background` property will *over-qualify* `background-color` or `background-image` properties because it carries more **weight**.

Comment: I tried doing that way too, but the color doesn't shows up.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. You can have a `background-color` **under** the image but since this is a **non-transparent** image it won't show up. If you want a color **over** the image...that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!

Just add the overlay this way::

```
.globe-img {position: relative;}

.globe-img::before {
 content: ""; 
 background-color: rgba(11, 135, 224, 0.95);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.globe-img > div {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: This works for me thank you so much. And I can ignore this z-index property that you have applied on other div elements is it? It still works good. Any reason for applying?

Comment: Yes you can ignore that if it works perfectly. I applied it because the overlay should not hide elements beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add blue background to globe-img class just add blue bg as below::

```
.globe-img {
  background: blue url('http://binarytheme.com/BTlivedemos/2014/10/20/blue-landing/assets/img/earth.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

There is specifically no need to add any inner div/elements for adding blue background.

Comment: So you want to add blue bg as a overlay on top of image? In the above code blue will work if the img is small than the relative divs height and width

Comment: It's not my question but it's not clear what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Am actually trying to replicate this site: http://binarytheme.com/BTlivedemos/2014/10/20/blue-landing/index.html